# How to move mail in outlook public subfolders that are 4 levels deep to 3 levels deep?

Tags: c#, api, powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I have a public folder structure like this:

- SPL_TEST

  - 2014

    - 214002 name

      - In
      - Email

        - BUT
        - SKR
    - 214005 name

      - In
      - Email

        - BUT
        - SKR
  - 2015

    - 215003 name

      - In
      - Email

        - BUT
        - SKR
    - 215004 name

      - In
      - Email

        - BUT
        - SKR

All mails are sorted under the BUT and SKR and more subfolders that is directly under the subfolder Email. I would like to move these mails directly under the Email folder, so that it will be easy to search through all the mail.

To do this manually is not an option, because there are more then 5000 folders.
I’ve searched for an easy solution in Powershell Script to run on the Exchange Server, but had no succes there. And I’ve tried to use the Outlook API to move them, but I don’t really know how to start.

It would be awesome if anyone could help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can look here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268996.aspx

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860636(v=office.15).aspx) and [Folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864011(v=office.15).aspx) properties for the Folder class that you may use for navigationg between folders. The [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx) method of Outlook items moves a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder.

You can find a sample code in the [How to: Enumerate Folders on All Stores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868170(v=office.15).aspx) article in MSDN.